# Form not getting submitted inside delegate event

Tags: jquery

I have a link which is generated dynamically through ajax calls. When clicking on the link the form should submit and do some PHP operations

Here is the code:

```
$( document ).on( "click", "a.submit-ssn-data", function() {
  $('#hidden_ssn').val($(this).text());
  $('form#frm-ssn-search').submit();
});
```

If I put an alert within **on**, I am getting the alert statement, also the hidden element value assignment also works. But the form only is not submitting. Can anyone please give me the idea to fix this issue. Thanks.

Comment: try `$('#frm-ssn-search')[0].submit();`

Comment: Nothing wrong with the posted code. Check for typos in class/id names, or look for `preventDefault()`/`return false` in a submit handler

Comment: What value will be shown when you try `alert($('form#frm-ssn-search').size())`?

Comment: I just alert a message. Alert is working but not submitting.

Comment: @ArunPJohny no luck :(

Comment: @Babin Lal I asked for the value. Was the value  zero or one?

Comment: Thanks for your responses. At last I got the issue. I used a submit button in the same form, which has the name  **submit**. I just renamed it to "Search". Finally it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you need to prevent the default action of the link but using `e.preventDefault()` or `return false;` in the handler. If the link has an `href`, the browser will follow the link, which will supercede the form submission.

```
$( document ).on( "click", "a.submit-ssn-data", function() {
  $('#hidden_ssn').val($(this).text());
  $('form#frm-ssn-search').submit();
  return false;
});
```

[Here's a live example that doesn't prevent the default](http://jsbin.com/kuveta/1), and we don't see the form submit; [here's one that does](http://jsbin.com/kuveta/2), and we *do* see the form submission.

Comment: What is the intension of `return false;` ? As far as I know, the execution of `submit()`generates a new request an the browser leaves the current page?

Comment: @reporter: To prevent the default action of clicking the link, which is of course, to follow the link. Completing the *current* action (following the link) takes precedence over the *new* action of submitting the form, unless we tell the browser not to do it (as we can see in the linked example).

Answer (score 0):

Check for the form elements (especially submit or buttons), which should not be named as **submit**. If so, just rename. The form will submit.